# Opening SMS app from feature phone's mobile browser?

Tags: html, sms, mobile-website, mobile-browser

Via HTML, is it possible to access/open the SMS app from a mobile browser?

It's okay if the SMS is routed through the user's own mobile carrier (like normally), and is billed to the said user as well. I don't want to create my own SMS gateway to provide a platform for sending such messages. I'm only interested in calling the SMS functionality from the mobile browser.

I've seen examples of: `<a href="sms://+14035550185">Send an SMS</a>` But I'm unsure how extensively they work. I need a robust solution that works across an expansive range of mobile browsers (esp. old-school feature phones). I don't want to have to use HTML5 or Javascript. Most old-school feature phone browsers I'm targeting aren't Javascript-enabled - so it's a bottleneck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I added the following in my template and got the desired results: `<a href="sms:+1234?body={{ link.description }}" style="color:blue;background-color:#FFA500">SMS</a>`

Don't mind the Django tag: `{{ link.description }}`

The generic usage for anyone is `<a href="sms:1234567?body=hello world">Send SMS</a>`

Comment: it is not working onLoad user have to specifically click on the link.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to add a pre-fabricated message to the sms, Android and iOS devices require slightly different syntax. Note the '&' vs '?' below.

iOS:

```
<a href="sms:1234&body=hi">Send an SMS</a>
```

Android:

```
<a href="sms:1234?body=hi">Send an SMS</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any information on which Android OS versions the code is compatible with?

Comment: This worked for me. In addition to this, do an encodeURIComponent() on your `body` text.

Comment: What If I don't want to add any default number?

Comment: event when I use encodeURIComponent() on Android, the `&` char is cutting my url.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for a feature phone's browser to send arbitrary SMS messages in response to some HTML page (that would be a **major** security vulnerability if it were possible...).

If you really want broad feature phone support you'll need to spin up a solution using an SMS gateway such as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/).  The phone's browser will GET / POST to your web application, then your web application will POST to Twilio to send the appropriate message.

Comment: I'm not really after 'sending' an SMS from the browser. Is it possible to access and open the SMS app from the mobile browser? I also fine-tuned the problem statement to reflect this.